# accessing the name and album info for a bunch of files

Tags: c#, vb.net, mp3

I'm trying to build a quick and dirty app, either in C# or VB.net. I need to load up either a list or an array (or something else I don't know about) with the corresponding data from the bunch of mp3 files so I can sort it based on album, then add an incrementing number to the beginning of the song title. I've ran into a bit of trouble and would appreciate any help. I think I should be able to finish it up but I'm having trouble with extracting the album name of the mp3 files. Any help rendered would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need a tag reader library unless you are going to recreate the wheel

Comment: You're looking for an ID3 tag reader.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that I was going to have to use a reader, and I was able to even generate the name of the files. Now I just need some help getting at the album name. Any suggestions?